# How do I find my logs in heroku?

Tags: python, logging, heroku

I'm in the process of moving my app over to heroku, and I'm having trouble getting access to my logs. I thought heroku combined all of the logs together, but my Python errors seem to be going somewhere else.

Currently getting an error on one of my pages (upload_add) with the message:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected internal server error

(generated by waitress)
```

However, the log simply says this:

```
    2016-12-13T17:14:02.163521+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-12-13T17:14:20.579420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manager/expenses?expense_group_id=1" host=singleentry.herokuapp.com request_id=527c4df0-4ebc-43f4-8edb-50926518947f fwd="75.49.124.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=814ms status=200 bytes=63770
    2016-12-13T17:14:25.998327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manager/expense?expense_id=497" host=singleentry.herokuapp.com request_id=74caaac6-7822-437a-83bd-66490809d1ae fwd="75.49.124.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=151ms status=200 bytes=48930
    2016-12-13T17:14:33.232730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/manager/upload_add" host=singleentry.herokuapp.com request_id=4e466bfc-464b-444e-96e2-98ef931b07cb fwd="75.49.124.130" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=625ms status=500 bytes=269
```

How do I go about finding out what this error is?

Comment: As far as I can tell the errors just end up in the normal logs. So try doing, `heroku logs --source app`. See the [documentation here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

Comment: The last line of the output of that command is "serving on http://0.0.0.0:47695"

Answer (score 0):

Click on your app name on the heroku website, then on 'more' and view logs! The other option is to check your terminal as well by typing:

```
heroku logs -t
```

Comment: The right answer to the wrong question, but appreciate the post